# send JSON object back to server in Django

Tags: javascript, html, json, django

I put the LinkedIn sign-in button in my Django based website. When the user sign in by LinkedIn account, LinkedIn will return a JSON object with information about the user. I would like to pass the JSON object back to server side to process and extract the information.

Please show me the way to do it, and (if it is possible) do it securely.

Thank you!

Comment: You will have to be more specific about what you need and what you have tried. The general answer is that you listen for it on a certain path in django and send it there using ajax.

Comment: Thank you @dlsso ! I think got it, thank you for the keyword, I will check the Ajax and try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the result from the LinkedIn, make an ajax call to your Django view from the browser like this:

```js
if(YOU_GOT_THE_RESULT){

    $.ajax({
       url: your_url,
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       data: JSON_DATA_YOU_GOT_FROM_LINKEDIN,
       statusCode: {
         200: function (your_Response_Data) {
            // YOUR SERVER'S RESPONSE
            // you can act on your server's 
            // response if there will be any
            // eg. you can send back information to update UI. 
          },
          // ... handle errors if required
          404: function () {
             // what to do on 404 etc.
          }
       },
       complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
          // Things to do after everything is completed
       }
    });
}
```

In your Django view, respond to this ajax request. If your view is only going to respond to ajax requests you can simply check `if request.is_ajax():` . This is a `post` request so your view should respond to posts. Data you're looking for is inside `request.POST`.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Tiny Instance! I did it! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) PS. To make it secure your connection to server has to be over https.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a JSON in python (actually a string with JSON format), you can use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library to get it back to a python object: `dict` or `list`

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
['foo', {'bar': ['baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that, I don't know how to send that JSON object from the view to server.